# Undeclared Identifier error in Compile

Tags: compile, warning-messages

I've been trying to compile a couple of functions in *Mathematica*, and I keep coming across an error that I do not know how to resolve.  Consider the following function:

```
FindCircleVerticalLineIntersections = 
  Compile[{{circlePos, _Real, 1}, {radius}, {xIntercept}},
   Module[{points, θ, posRadius, yDist},
    (*First, let's initialize points*)
    (*This will not work any other way that I have tried*)
    points = {{0.0, 0.0}};

    (*First things first:  
    let's see if the vertical line is within the boundaries of the \
circle*)
    If[PointIsWithinCircleWidth[circlePos, radius, {xIntercept, 0}],
     (*If it is, let's see if it is right on the edge of the circle*)


     If[PointIsOnCircleWidth[circlePos, radius, {xIntercept, 0}],
       (*If it is, 
       then the list of all intersection points will have just one \
entry*)
       points = {{xIntercept, circlePos[[2]]}};
       ,
       (*Otherwise, let's find both intersections*)
       posRadius = Abs[radius];
       θ = ArcCos[(xIntercept - circlePos[[1]])/posRadius];
       yDist = posRadius*Sin[θ];
       points = {{xIntercept, circlePos[[2]] + yDist}, {xIntercept, 
          circlePos[[2]] - yDist}};
       ];
     ,
     (*Otherwise, we don't have any intersections, 
     let's just set points to an empty list*)
     points = Delete[points, 1];
     ];

    (*Finally, let's return points*)
    points
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Now, this function works just as expected, and returns results well, but whenever I try to call it from any other compiled function, such as the following function:

```
f = Compile[{},
   FindCircleVerticalLineIntersections[{0.0, 0.0}, 1.0, 0.0]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

I get the following undeclared identifier error:

> CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: C:\Users\Surge\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\combinatoric-5700\Working-combinatoric-5700-2808-88\compiledFunction87.c(85) : error C2065: 'P1' : undeclared identifier >>

I've looked at the human-readable C form of this program, and I don't even see an identifier called `P1`:

```
        No argument
        2 Integer registers
        2 Real registers
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(I1)0 = {0, 0}
        I1 = 1
        I0 = 3
        Result = T(R2)1

1   T(R2)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[FindCircleVerticalLineIntersections][ \
T(I1)0, I1, I1]]
2   Return
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**EDIT**

Here are the missing functions, my apologies for the delay:

```
    (*The following function determines wither a point pointPos is within \
a circle of a given radius centered on the origin*)
PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin = 
  Compile[{{radius}, {pointPos, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{posRad},
    (*First, 
    let's make sure the radius that was passed in is positive*)
    posRad = Abs[radius];

    (*Next, let's see if the X-
    componant of the point is within the boundary of the circle*)
    (*This If structure to my knowledge is unnecessary, 
    but it makes the code look a bit cleaner in my opinion since we \
are explictly passing back a True or a False*)
    If[Abs[pointPos[[1]]] <= posRad,
     True,
     False
     ]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

(*The following function determines whether some point pPos is within \
a circle of radius rad centered at cPos*)
PointIsWithinCircleWidth = 
  Compile[{{cPos, _Real, 1}, {rad}, {pPos, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{pos, pRad},
    (*First, 
    let's shift the entire system so that we can be dealing with a \
circle centered at the origin*)
    pos = pPos - cPos;

    (*Next, 
    let's call PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin and return whatever \
that returns*)
    PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin[rad, pos]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

(*This function determines whether a given point is on the left-most \
or right-most boundary of a circle on the origin given a radius*)
PointIsOnCircleWidthOnOrigin = Compile[{{radius}, {point, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{positiveRad, posXComponant},
    (*Let's first make sure the radius is positive*)
    positiveRad = Abs[radius];

    (*Next, let's find the absolute value of the X-componant*)
    posXComponant = Abs[point[[1]]];

    If[posXComponant == positiveRad,
     True,
     False
     ]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

(*This function determines whether a point is on the left-most or \
right-most boundary of a circle on the origin given a radius*)
PointIsOnCircleWidth = 
  Compile[{{cPos, _Real, 1}, {radius}, {point, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{pos},
    pos = point - cPos;

    PointIsOnCircleWidthOnOrigin[radius, pos]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Comment: I upvoted your question because I think this probably should not happen. However, it is not really answerable without the definitions of `PointIsWithinCircleWidth` and `PointIsOnCircleWidth` given, so please include those in the question as well. Welcome to the site, by the way. It is a rarer thing than you would think for a brand-new user to post a (almost) fully formed and properly formatted question, and it is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [`"InlineCompiledFunctions"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html)?

Comment: I am sorry, but without those definitions, the issue is not reproducible and so the question is not answerable. Therefore I have to vote to close your question as it currently is. If it is closed before you are able to update it, please cast a vote to re-open after you have done so, and I'm sure other users will follow suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call compiled functions inside another compiled function, you should consider to inline them. You can do this by wrapping a `With` statement around and using

```
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
```

as option to compile. I have cleaned your code, moving a lot of definitions of variable right where you declare it in `Module`. I have remove all the compilation targets and `"Speed"` runtime options and only used it in the very last `FindCircleVerticalLineIntersections` function. The function `PointIsWithinCircleWidth` contains an error because you declare `pos` and `pRad` in the `Module` but you don't give them values. I fixed this, but you need to check whether it is what you meant!

You can download the complete notebook at once by evaluating

```
Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxbnd.png"]
```

or you copy&paste it from below. The final function should work now:

```
PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin = 
  Compile[{{radius, _Real, 0}, {pointPos, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{posRad = Abs[radius]},
    If[Abs[pointPos[[1]]] <= posRad, True, False]]];


PointIsWithinCircleWidth = 
  With[{PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin = 
     PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin},
   Compile[{{cPos, _Real, 1}, {rad, _Real, 0}, {pPos, _Real, 1}}, 
    Module[{pos = cPos - pPos, pRad = rad}, 
     PointIsWithinCircleWidthOnOrigin[rad, pos]
     ],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
    ]
   ];

PointIsOnCircleWidthOnOrigin = 
  Compile[{{radius}, {point, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{positiveRad = Abs[radius], posXComponant = Abs[point[[1]]]},
    If[posXComponant == positiveRad, True, False]]
   ];


PointIsOnCircleWidth =
  With[{PointIsOnCircleWidthOnOrigin = PointIsOnCircleWidthOnOrigin},
   Compile[{{cPos, _Real, 1}, {radius, _Real, 0}, {point, _Real, 1}}, 
    Module[{pos = point - cPos},
     PointIsOnCircleWidthOnOrigin[radius, pos]],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
    ]
   ];

FindCircleVerticalLineIntersections =
  With[{
    PointIsWithinCircleWidth = PointIsWithinCircleWidth,
    PointIsOnCircleWidth = PointIsOnCircleWidth
    },
   Compile[{{circlePos, _Real, 1}, {radius}, {xIntercept}}, 
    Module[{points = {{0.0, 0.0}}, \[Theta], posRadius, yDist},
     If[PointIsWithinCircleWidth[circlePos, radius, {xIntercept, 0}], 
      If[PointIsOnCircleWidth[circlePos, radius, {xIntercept, 0}], 
       points = {{xIntercept, circlePos[[2]]}},
       posRadius = Abs[radius];
       \[Theta] = ArcCos[(xIntercept - circlePos[[1]])/posRadius];
       yDist = posRadius*Sin[\[Theta]];
       points = {{xIntercept, circlePos[[2]] + yDist}, {xIntercept, 
          circlePos[[2]] - yDist}}
       ],
      points = Delete[points, 1]
      ];
     points
     ],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Comment: What was the problem, though?  I'm more interested in learning the inner workings of Mathematica than just getting code that works.

Comment: Beside the error in `PointIsWithinCircleWidth` that I pointed out, you cannot simply call a compiled function from within another compiled function and expect that it is properly included (injected). The combination of `With` and the option `"InlineCompiledFunctions"` is important because otherwise when you call your compiled function, it calls back to *Mathematica* which is not what you want. You want a compiled function to be fast compiled code only without callbacks to the Mathematica Kernel. The real problem was that with compilation target `"C"` this produced not only slow code...

Comment: ...In your example, it gave a cryptic error. I couldn't even reproduce your error on my Linux machine. Here, the Kernel just crashed. Therefore, I can only tell you how to do it right and not, what exactly went wrong in your specific case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Is this documented anywhere?  The documentation in the help page of Mathematica is woefully insufficient on these  particular points discussed here.

Comment: @Surge You mean the options to compile? Sure, see the [Details and Options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) section of `Compile` and follow the links. In the doc of [`CompilationOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html) you'll find examples.